# I can't log into Pokemon GO because of "GPS signal not found" message

Tags: pokemon-go

[image]

This is very annoying. We just bought a phone (android 5.1) and all location services are on and the mock location is off. Still got no GPS signal.

Once I click log in with Google, it won't load at all. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: When you say it won't load at all, do you get the Gyrados warning screen?

Comment: No, it just will not load like try to log in and when it does the spinning pokeball thing it just keeps doing it. Is there a way to post a picture so I can show you better?

Comment: Please see [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/how-do-i-add-a-picture-to-a-stack-exchange-post) link on how to add an image to your post.

Comment: It could possibly be a bug with the Pokemon GO app itself. Have you tried using a different app that relies on GPS, like Google Maps, to see if the GPS is working in that app? Note that it way take a few moments to acquire GPS signal based on your location. There are many factors that can affect your GPS signal. It's best to try out in a clear open area so you can see as much of the sky as possible.

Comment: I'm on my phone so the link doesn't work.. And on his new phone google maps picks ups the gps right away, I tryed to go outside with it and it didn't help..

Comment: For the Pokemon GO app, is the location settings set to high accuracy?

Comment: Yes I have turned it off and back on and made sure it is definitely on high accuracy

Comment: @Sean i posted the picture if that helps

Comment: I had this issue before when walking around a large mall. All i did was use wifi instead of cellaur data and seemed to fix it for me.

Comment: @Will309 that is what the phone is on,, only wifi i dont have data for it yet

Comment: By any chance have you turned on `Mock Location` setting under developer options? That might be an issue.

Comment: Has it worked at all? I occasionally get this, but if I wait a bit and restart the phone, it seems rectify itself.

Comment: @RebelxChildx If you're trying to connect to WiFi where it isn't available, you'll get this issue - When not near a WiFi hotspot, try using Mobile Data (4G, etc).

Comment: Make sure your "Google Maps"-app and "Google Play Services" are updated. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible solutions:

1. Settings --> Privacy and safety --> Location: Check if "Location" is `On`. Then click on Location method and enable the method including GPS, Wifi and mobile networks
2. Switch Airplane mode `On`, wait half a minute or so, then turn in `Off` again
3. Make sure that Wifi is turned on, even if you are in a non-Wifi area (see 1.)
4. Go outdoors into an area where you can see a big part of the sky
5. Restart the app (make sure you properly close it)
6. Restart your phone and check with another app if your location is found before you start Pokemon Go
7. Check if you have the latest version of Pokemon Go installed
8. I think in newer Android versions than mine, you can specifically set permissions for each app individually. If that is the case, check if Pokemon Go is allowed to use the GPS
9. I am sure there is something more... I'll update this list if somebody comes up with another idea